# Any descriptive struts2 api doc for tags?

Tags: java, api, struts2

Folks I am trying to find good tags api doc on net but could not find any good one which is
descriptive. Everywhere I get this link reference http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/if.html
For example if I have to figure out if myManager in below if tag will be treated string literal or OGNL expression
against valueStack, I can not find any decription for this.

```
<s:if test="myManager">
 </s:if>
```

Can someone point me to good doc/link?

Comment: May be you should check out about OGNL first? http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html

Comment: From the link you have posted: `test` attribute description "Expression to determine if body of tag is to be displayed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will help you, as this site is also listed as article on apache official site.
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts-2-tags.shtml  as well as
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

In the reference you posted there is a column *Evaluated* which means if the specified value of the attribute is evaluated as an OGNL expression or treated literally to find value on the ValueStack.

Check also the Tag Syntax documentation.
http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/tag-syntax.html